# discord.js member count - Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have been trying to create a member count on my discord server. My code isn't working, I keep getting "Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined".

```
module.exports = (client) => {
  const channelId = '810343814517489664'

  const updateMembers = (guild) => {
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
    channel.setName(`Members: ${guild.memberCount.toLocaleString()}`)
  }

  client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => updateMembers(member.guild))
  client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => updateMembers(member.guild))

  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('464316540490088448')
  updateMembers(guild)
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `member.guild` is undefined or doesn't contain a property named `channels`. Are you able to dump values to a console for troubleshooting? I would start with `members` or `members.guild` to see exactly what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

You channel is undefined because you are not asking for it the right way.
You can ask for it :

```
const channelId = guild.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID');
```

Next below I will explain and show you what I am using for member counter!

```
module.exports = async (client) =>{
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD ID');
    setInterval(() =>{
        const memberCount = guild.memberCount;
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL ID');
        channel.setName(`Members:${memberCount.toLocaleString()}`);
        console.log('Updating Member Count');
    }, 3600000);//I set the update time every 1 hour!
}
```

**You need to create a voice channel for start and then the bot will rename it every time you will set the update!**

In your main file **(like index.js)** you need to **require for counter**.So you need to create a folder in your **main folder with name counters**. Inside this folder **('counters')** you need to create a file named **'member-counter.js'** and you paste the code above. In your main file **(like index.js)** you require it with :

```
const memberCounter = require('./counters/member-counter');
```

You go next in line that having the `client.on(ready)` function and set in last line :

```
memberCounter(client);
```

What i mean is :

```
client.on('ready', () => {
console.log('I am ready')
memberCounter(client);
});
```